# Simple user input in QGIS with pyqt plugin

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-2, pyqt

[SplitPolygon](https://github.com/uilic/SplitPolygon) plugin allows the user to enter an angle by which the polygon(s) will be split. I would like to modify the plugin and take that value from graphical user input (say, parallel with one side of the polygon). So how does one get simple graphical user input in QGIS? Is there something like Utility in AutoCAD's VBA for points, angles, rectangles?

Just to make it clear, I want the user to select two points and the code should either get the two points or the angle directly.